# Daily overwrite of Azure cloud SQL database from on-prem SQL database

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

We've got a web app we are building that uses a copy of our client's on-prem sql DB, and our copy is hosted on Azure. Nightly, we need to essentially overwrite our Azure db with all of the contents of the on-prem db. The db is only 5 tables or so, so it's not huge.

We have discussed a few possibilities: BCP run on an azure functions from some CSV exports they take every night, Having them export a bacpac and push it up to blob storage and re-creating the DB nightly, etc etc etc....

I know there's no "right" answer here, but I was hoping for some opinions on how others might handle this process. Thanks!

Comment: And what about scheduling a daily snapshot replication from on-perm SQL Server instance to Azure SQL database? For more information, please refer to this [BOL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt589530.aspx) page.

Answer (score 0):

We use different solutions based on the needs of our projects, but you can choose the one that best fits our needs. Options are

1. [Data lake](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-move-data-between-onprem-and-cloud)
2. [Azure Web Job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-create-web-jobs) - an executable that can run a CRON Job.
3. Azure Function as you already mentioned